# Switch from Power BI Live Mode to Import Model

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I am connected to **Tabular Model** via **Live Mode** in Power BI. Is there a way I can change from Live Mode to Import Mode. I remember in older versions of Power BI at bottom right corner we used to have the flexibility to change it from Live to Import Mode, however I don't see that anymore in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe once you create a power bi file with a live connection to SSAS, you cannot change the storage mode to Import. I found the following question and answer on Microsoft documentation, not the exact question but similar. Basically says you cannot mix or change storage modes for SSAS live connection.

> Question: If I created a live connection, can I connect to another data source in the same Power BI Desktop file?

> Answer: No. You can't explore live data and connect to another type of data source in the same file. If you’ve already imported data or connected to a different data source in a Power BI Desktop file, you need to create a new file to explore live.

Reference: [Connect to Analysis Services tabular data in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data)

Answer (score 1):

Switching from Live connection to Import mode currently is not supported. You can [vote](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18556393-support-switching-ssas-connect-model-from-connect) for this idea, if you want to. You should create a new report and copy/paste as much as possible from your existing report.